# Bing Maps Silverlight Extended Modes API

Tags: silverlight, api, bing-maps

I need to have this API badly quickly. I went on Microsoft Connect but there is nothing even wasted the whole day making research on forums but found no suitable answer.

Can you please just upload it somewhere and put link here?

Umair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and it was just there on Microsoft connect website.

Comment: you should leave the link so other people can find it.